# Mongoose pull object from array inside array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pull

I am currently using Node.js with Mongoose to manipulate an MongoDB database. I would like remove an object from an array itself inside an array.

```
var newTable = new module.Table({
  "_id": ObjectId("1"),
  "name": "Table1",
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("11"),
      "name": "Item1",
      "subscribers": [
        {
          "itemId": "111"
        },
        {
          "itemId": "112"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}).save();
```

I've tried this query but it has no effect:

```
module.Table.update(
  { "items._id": "11" },
  { $pull: { "items.$.subscribers": { "itemId": "112" } } },
  { "safe": true },
  function (err, obj) {
    if (err) console.log(filename + " @ module.Table.update(): " + err);
  }
);
```

Please help me how to query.

> Note1: ObjectId("xxx") are simplified references for this example.
>
> Note2: I found the bug, it's a mistake of my part, the query need the id as string (not as ObjectId).

Comment: first thing I see is that you have `{ "itemId": ObjectId("112") } }`. you realize that javascript doesn't have objectId.  you might need to do something like : `new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca')` that will convert something to object Id to check the object ID in the DB. and it looks like your objectIds are invalid. So I don't know how your working with those objectIDs. what errors are you getting?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to explain that ObjectId("xxx") are simplified references for this example.

Answer (score 0):

While jack blank is partially right in the comments, I wanted to clarify this answer further as I had trouble with it.
In my case, the solution was the following:

1. Import mongoose in your script (note the way it is imported).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

2. Then make sure you that in the case you are updating many documents you use updateMany()

```
await Order.updateMany({},{
  $pull: {
    'products': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
  },
}).exec();
```

**Note** that the ObjectId is **NOT** `new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId()` but rather `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`.